# Uploading files to the same directory as the script using php

Tags: php, file-upload

Using `move_uploaded_file("temp_location","new_location")`, is there a way to upload files to the same directory as the file uploading script when specifying the `"new_location"` or does it always have to be uploaded in another specified folder within the script's directory?

Comment: To answer your question, yes it can be done

Comment: i mean, you could always use [getcwd()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Comment: No reason you can't so that as long as you have permissions on the directory to allow for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, as long as you have the permission to write in that specific directory:

```
/* new_file can be any path ... */
$new_file = __DIR__ . '/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];

if ( is_writable(dirname($new_file)) ) {
    move_upload_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $new_file );
} else {
    throw new Exception( 'File upload failed: Directory is not writable.' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload file in script directory as following code .

HTML code :-

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

PHP code:-

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],   "". $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

But a problem in the case of permission.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dirname` and `__FILE__` for that:

```
move_uploaded_file($tmpName, dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $newName);
```

Comment: Just as another option: `__DIR__` is exactly same as `dirname( __FILE__ )` and is more readable IMO.